# Test is not using same asset as application in flutter local package

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I moved the login screen of my application to a local package and the image on that screen is still showing without changing its path (`'assets/images/logo.png'`).
But when I added a widget test in the package I had error: **Unable to load asset**.

Here's the project structure:

```
|-- assets
    |-- images
        |-- logo.png     <-- the image
|-- lib
|-- packages
    |- login_screen      <-- the local package
```

and the `pubspec.yaml`:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  login_screen:
    path: packages/login_screen

flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/images/
```

`login_screen.dart`:

```
class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const LoginScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(50),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png'),
            Spacer(),
            OutlinedButton(onPressed: (){}, child: Text('Login')),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The first thing I did is to move the image into the package and updated its `pubspec.yaml` to use the asset. That fixed the test issue but broke the application which couldn't find the asset anymore.

I did read a lot to understand how packages work in Flutter but I couldn't make it. The only way to make both app and test work is duplicating the asset.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You can try these steps after adding new assets:

1. Stop debug or uninstall the app from the phone or emulator

[image]

2. Flutter clean, flutter pub get
3. Start debug

Comment: I tried these steps but still same behavior.